# Lookup from another table to update a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've been struggling with this for quite a while and can't seem to find the correct statement (even with the help of google!)

What I'm trying to do is... (and I really hope this makes sense)

Lookup value1 in table1 from value1 in table2 (to match)
Then update value2 in table1 from table2 value2 where the first values match

so far I have..

```
inner join table2 on table1.value1
inner join table2 on table1.value2

update table1

set value2=table2.value2
where value1=table2.value1
```

Comment: Ignore the UPDATE bit for now. Can you write a SELECT statement that returns the desired result?

Comment: I hope the names you have on tables and columns are not the ones you show.

Comment: Have a look at the instructions at http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/31/update-data-in-one-table-with-data-from-another-table/, maybe one of those approaches works with MySQL, too.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this is what you are after:

```
update table1
  join table2
    on table1.value1 = table2.value1
set table1.value2 = table2.value2;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8982d/1

#### Update:

If you are using SQL Server (I see you have that tag in the question as well), then it's normal that you get the *"syntax error newar JOIN"* error message.

That's because in SQL Server the syntax is a bit different:

```
update table1
    set table1.value2 = table2.value2
from table1
join table2
  on table1.value1 = table2.value1
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4139c/1

Comment: For some reason it didn't like the word join

Comment: @JonJBBarlow are you using MySQL? Here's an online demo using MySQL 5: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8982d/1 that shows it working

Comment: @JonJBBarlow If you're using SQL Server, see the update to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You want a join with an update in mysql.  The syntax is:

```
update table1 join
       table2
       on table1.value1 = table2.value1
    set table1.value2 = table2.value2;
```

Comment: Thank you. What actually worked is 

update table1
set table1.value2 = table2.value2
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.value1 = table2.value1


Thanks to all that helped